# J2ME Polish - Unable to execute J2ME Polish task: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The property [dir.dist] is not defined in input [${dir.dist}]

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, java-me, j2mepolish

I am trying to get a J2ME Polish sample project up and running, but am struggling.

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 with the J2ME Polish plugin.

When I try to create a J2ME Polish project (`File` > `New Project` > `Java ME` > `J2ME Polish Project`), the `New Project` wizard works fine until I get to the last step, at which point clicking the `Finish` button does not do anything. I then have to close the wizard and open the project manually (which appears to have been created - although maybe not fully?).

Next, I fix the resource complaint by referencing `enough-j2mepolish-client.jar` after I have relocated it to root of my project.

I then try to clean and build the project, but I get this error in my `Output` window:

```
ant -f M:\\Netbeans\\J2ME-Polish-Project rebuild
clean:
Deleting directory M:\Netbeans\J2ME-Polish-Project\build
pre-init:
pre-load-properties:
exists.config.active:
exists.netbeans.user:
exists.user.properties.file:
load-properties:
exists.platform.active:
exists.platform.configuration:
exists.platform.profile:
basic-init:
cldc-pre-init:
cldc-init:
cdc-init:
semc-pre-init:
semc-init:
savaje-pre-init:
savaje-init:
sjmc-pre-init:
sjmc-init:
ojec-pre-init:
ojec-init:
cdc-hi-pre-init:
cdc-hi-init:
nokiaS80-pre-init:
nokiaS80-init:
post-init:
init:
j2mepolish-init:
j2mepolish:
J2ME Polish 2.4 (2013-08-27) (GPL License)
Loading device database...
Processing [7] devices...
building application for [Generic/jtwi] (1/7):
using locale [de_DE]...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The property [dir.dist] is not defined in input [${dir.dist}]
    at de.enough.polish.Environment.getProperty(Environment.java:537)
    at de.enough.polish.Environment.writeProperties(Environment.java:452)
    at de.enough.polish.ant.build.BuildSetting.getDestDir(BuildSetting.java:621)
    at de.enough.polish.ant.PolishTask.initialize(PolishTask.java:1613)
    at de.enough.polish.ant.PolishTask.execute(PolishTask.java:600)
    at de.enough.polish.ant.PolishTask.execute(PolishTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
M:\Netbeans\J2ME-Polish-Project\build.xml:82: Unable to execute J2ME Polish task: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The property [dir.dist] is not defined in input [${dir.dist}]
    at de.enough.polish.Environment.getProperty(Environment.java:537)
    at de.enough.polish.Environment.writeProperties(Environment.java:452)
    at de.enough.polish.ant.build.BuildSetting.getDestDir(BuildSetting.java:621)
    at de.enough.polish.ant.PolishTask.initialize(PolishTask.java:1613)
    at de.enough.polish.ant.PolishTask.execute(PolishTask.java:600)
    at de.enough.polish.ant.PolishTask.execute(PolishTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

As well as J2ME Polish, I'm also brand new to Ant, so maybe this could be a simple one to solve (although I haven't managed after 1 hour...).

For completeness, here is my `build.xml` file:

```
<!-- When you are using NetBeans 5, just rename this file     -->
<!-- to build.xml. You can then use the normal menu items     -->
<!-- run, debug, build and so forth from within NetBeans.     -->

<!-- This file controls the build process.                    -->
<!-- The most important target is the "j2mepolish",           -->
<!-- which controls for what devices the application should   -->
<!-- be created and so on.                                    -->
<!--                                                          -->
<!-- Call the "emulator" target to skip the obfuscation       -->
<!-- and to build the example for only one handsets.          -->
<!-- The default target builds and obfuscates the example.    -->
<!--                                                          -->
<!-- The full documentation can be found at                   -->
<!-- http://www.j2mepolish.org                                -->
<!--                                                          -->
<!-- Have fun!                                                -->
<project 
    name="J2ME-Polish-Project" 
    default="j2mepolish">

    <!-- extend the default NetBeans build script:           -->
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <!-- The polish.home property needs to point to the directory -->
    <!-- containing the J2ME Polish installation.                 -->
    <property name="polish.home" location="P:\Program Files\J2ME-Polish" />

    <!-- import global properties                                 -->
    <property file="${polish.home}/global.properties" />


    <!-- Definition of the J2ME Polish task:                      -->
    <taskdef name="j2mepolish" 
        classname="de.enough.polish.ant.PolishTask" 
        classpath="${polish.home}/lib/enough-j2mepolish-build.jar"
    />


    <!-- build targets, each target can be called via "ant [name]", 
         e.g. "ant clean", "ant test j2mepolish" or just "ant" for calling the default-target -->

    <target name="setdeploy" 
        description="Call this target first to set the OTA download-URL, e.g. ant setdeploy j2mepolish"
        >
        <property name="deploy-url" value="http://www.company.com/download/" />
    </target>

    <target name="enableDebug" 
        description="Call this target first to skip the obfuscation step, call the emulator and start the debugger, e.g. ant enableDebug j2mepolish"
        >
        <property name="debug" value="true" />
    </target>


    <target name="test" 
        description="Call this target first to skip the obfuscation step and call the emulator, e.g. ant test j2mepolish"
        >
        <property name="test" value="true" />
        <property name="dir.work" value="build/test" />
    </target>

    <target name="j2mepolish-init"
            depends="init"
        >
        <property name="test" value="false" />
        <property name="dir.work" value="build/real" />
        <property name="deploy-url" value="" />
    </target>

    <!-- In this target the J2ME Polish task is used.             -->
    <!-- It has 3 sections:                                       -->
    <!--    1. The info-section defines some general information  -->
    <!--    2. The deviceRequirements-section chooses the devices -->
    <!--       for which the application is optimized.            -->
    <!--    3. The build-section controls the actual build        -->
    <!--       process.                                           -->   
    <target name="j2mepolish" 
            depends="j2mepolish-init"
            description="This is the controller for the J2ME build process." 
            >
        <j2mepolish>
            <!-- general settings, these settings basically form the JAD-attributes. -->
            <!-- Have a look at the <jad>-section for setting specialised attributes.
                 You can also define localized attributes in the resources/messages.txt files -->
            <info
                name="J2ME Polish"
                version="1.3.4"
                description="A simple project that uses localization."
                vendorName="Enough Software"
                infoUrl="http://www.j2mepolish.org"
                icon="dot.png"
                jarName="${polish.vendor}-${polish.name}-${polish.locale}-menu.jar" 
                jarUrl="${deploy-url}${polish.jarName}"
                copyright="Copyright 2005 - 2011 Enough Software. All rights reserved."
                deleteConfirm="Do you really want to kill me?" 
            />
            <!-- selection of supported devices -->
            <deviceRequirements if="config.active:defined and (test or enableCompilerMode)" >       
                <requirement name="Identifier" value="${config.active}" />
            </deviceRequirements>
            <deviceRequirements if="device:defined and (test or enableCompilerMode)" unless="config.active:defined">
                <requirement name="Identifier" value="${device}" />
            </deviceRequirements>
            <deviceRequirements unless="test or enableCompilerMode">
                <requirement name="Identifier" value="${devices}" />
            </deviceRequirements>
            <!-- build settings -->
            <!-- 
             -->
            <build
                usePolishGui="true"
                workDir="${dir.work}"
                destDir="${dir.dist}"
                compilerMode="${enableCompilerMode}"
                compilerDestDir="build/classes"
                compilerModePreverify="true"
            >
                <!-- midlets definition, NetBeans defines all MIDlets in the Ant property manifest.midlets:  -->
                <midlets definition="${manifest.midlets}" if="manifest.midlets:defined" />
                <midlets unless="manifest.midlets:defined">
                    <midlet class="de.enough.polish.example.MenuMidlet" name="Example" />
                </midlets>
                <!-- project-wide variables - used for preprocessing.  -->
                <!-- You can set localized variables in the resources/messages.txt files as well.  -->
                <variables includeAntProperties="true" >
                    <!-- use the advanced menubar mode that offers near-native command handling and positioning, on BB and Android use native commands: -->
                    <variable
                        name="polish.FullScreen"
                        value="menu" 
                        unless="polish.blackberry || polish.android" 
                    />
                    <variable name="polish.MenuBar.useExtendedMenuBar" value="true" />
                    <!-- example variables:
                    In your Java-code you can use the following snipet to use this variable:
                    //#= private static final String UPDATE_URL = "${ update-url }";
                    You can change the title of the sample application with the "title"-var.
                    -->
                    <variable name="update-url" value="http://www.enough.de/update" />
                    <variable name="title" value="J2ME Polish" />
                </variables>
                <!-- Here you can set the dir attribute to "resources2" for an alternative design. -->
                <resources
                    dir="resources/base"
                    defaultexcludes="yes"
                    excludes="readme.txt"
                >
                    <root dir="resources/customizations/${customization}" if="${customization}.enabled" />
                    <!-- add the localization element for created localized
                         versions of your application: -->
                    <localization locales="de_DE, en_US" unless="test" />
                    <localization locales="en_US" if="test" />
                </resources>
                <!-- obfuscator settings: do not obfuscate when the test-property is true -->
                <obfuscator name="ProGuard" unless="test or polish.blackberry" >
                    <!--
                    You can set additional parameters here, e.g.:
                    <parameter name="optimize" value="false" />
                    -->
                </obfuscator>
                <!-- debug settings: only include debug setting when the test-property is true -->
                <debug if="test or log" verbose="true" level="error">
                    <filter pattern="de.enough.polish.example.*" level="debug" />
                    <filter pattern="de.enough.polish.ui.*" level="warn" />
                    <!-- activate display handler to see log entries in real time:
                    <handler name="display" />
                    -->
                </debug>
                <!-- user defined JAD attributes can also be used: -->
                <jad>
                    <attribute name="Nokia-MIDlet-Category" value="Game" if="polish.group.Series40" />
                </jad>  
                <!-- 
                   This is an example for signing MIDlets with J2ME Polish. 
                   You can set the password on the commandline by calling "ant -Dpassword=secret",
                   or by setting the Ant property above.
                   Signing is done only for MIDP/2.0 devices.
                -->
                <!--
                <sign
                    key="SignMIDlet"
                    keystore="midlets.ks"
                    password="${password}"
                    unless="test"
                />
                -->
            </build>

            <!-- execution of emulator(s) -->
            <emulator
                wait="true"
                trace="class"
                securityDomain="trusted"
                enableProfiler="true"
                enableMemoryMonitor="true"
                enableNetworkMonitor="true"
                if="test and not debug"
                >
                <!--
                <parameter name="-Xjam" value="transient=http://localhost:8080/${polish.jadName}" />
                -->
            </emulator>

            <emulator
                wait="true"
                trace="class"
                securityDomain="trusted"
                enableProfiler="false"
                enableMemoryMonitor="false"
                enableNetworkMonitor="false"
                if="debug"
                >
                <!-- Attach the emulator to the NetBeans debugger:  -->
                <debugger name="antcall" target="connect-debugger" port="6001" />
            </emulator>


        </j2mepolish>
    </target>

    <target 
        name="emulator"
        depends="test,j2mepolish"
        description="invokes the emulator"
    >
    </target>

    <target name="clean" 
            description="allows a clean build. You should call [ant clean] whenever you made changes to devices.xml, vendors.xml or groups.xml">
        <delete dir="build" />
        <delete dir="dist" includes="**/*" />
    </target>

    <target  
        name="cleanbuild"
        description="allows a clean build. You should call [ant cleanbuild] whenever you made changes to devices.xml, vendors.xml or groups.xml"
        depends="clean, j2mepolish"
    />

    <target name="debug" description="debugs the project" depends="enableDebug, test, j2mepolish" />

    <target name="deploy"
            description="Deploys the applications. Currently empty."
            depends="j2mepolish"
    />

    <target name="enableBarbie">
        <property name="customization" value="Barbie" />
        <property name="Barbie.enabled" value="true" />
    </target>

    <target name="barbie"
            description="customizes this project with the settings found in resources/customizations/Barbie"
            depends="enableBarbie, j2mepolish"
    />


    <target name="enableFrogger">
        <property name="customization" value="Frogger" />
        <property name="Frogger.enabled" value="true" />
    </target>

    <target name="frogger"
            description="customizes this project with the settings found in resources/customizations/Barbie"
            depends="enableFrogger, j2mepolish"
    />

    <target name="enableAnimations">
        <property name="customization" value="Animations" />
        <property name="Animations.enabled" value="true" />
        <property name="polish.MenuBar.useExtendedMenubar" value="true" />
    </target>

    <target name="animations"
            description="customizes this project with the settings found in resources/customizations/Animations"
            depends="enableAnimations, j2mepolish"
    />

    <target 
        name="build-all"
        description="Builds your application in all customizations." 
        >
        <subant target="j2mepolish" buildpath="." genericantfile="build.xml" inheritall="false" ></subant>
        <subant target="frogger" buildpath="." genericantfile="build.xml" inheritall="false" ></subant>
        <subant target="barbie" buildpath="." genericantfile="build.xml" inheritall="false" ></subant>
        <subant target="animations" buildpath="." genericantfile="build.xml" inheritall="false" ></subant>
    </target>

    <!-- NetBeans specific build targets: -->

            <target name="run" 
                    depends="test, j2mepolish"
            >
            </target>

            <target name="rebuild" 
                    depends="clean, j2mepolish"
            >
            </target>

            <target name="rebuild-all" 
                    depends="clean, j2mepolish"
            >
            </target>

            <target name="jar" 
                    depends="j2mepolish"
            >
            </target>

            <target name="jar-all" 
                    depends="j2mepolish"
            >
            </target>

            <target name="clean-all" 
                    depends="clean"
            >
            </target>

            <target name="deploy-all" 
                    depends="deploy"
            >
            </target>

            <target name="enable-compiler-mode">
                <property name="enableCompilerMode" value="true" />
            </target>

            <target name="compile-single" 
                    depends="enable-compiler-mode, j2mepolish"
            >
            </target>

        <target name="connect-debugger">
            <property name="jpda.port" value="${polish.debug.port}" />
            <antcall target="nbdebug"/>
        </target>


</project>
```

Any help much appreciated.

**Update: (17-Feb-2015)**
I have added `<property name="dir.dist" value="dist" />` (right after the existing `<property name="dir.work" value="build/real" />` line), but now I get this error when trying to clean/build the project:

```
ant -f M:\\Netbeans\\J2ME-Polish-Project rebuild
clean:
Deleting directory M:\Netbeans\J2ME-Polish-Project\build
pre-init:
pre-load-properties:
exists.config.active:
exists.netbeans.user:
exists.user.properties.file:
load-properties:
exists.platform.active:
exists.platform.configuration:
exists.platform.profile:
basic-init:
cldc-pre-init:
cldc-init:
cdc-init:
semc-pre-init:
semc-init:
savaje-pre-init:
savaje-init:
sjmc-pre-init:
sjmc-init:
ojec-pre-init:
ojec-init:
cdc-hi-pre-init:
cdc-hi-init:
nokiaS80-pre-init:
nokiaS80-init:
post-init:
init:
j2mepolish-init:
j2mepolish:
J2ME Polish 2.4 (2013-08-27) (GPL License)
Loading device database...
Processing [7] devices...
building application for [Generic/jtwi] (1/7):
using locale [de_DE]...
M:\Netbeans\J2ME-Polish-Project\build.xml:83: build.xml line 0: found no operator before symbol [.enabled] in term [${customization}.enabled] (both symbol and term might be simplified).
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: I am very sorry to ask this but why are you developing J2ME in 2015? It is died about 7 years ago!

Comment: It hasn't died everywhere. I think it is still quite prominent in a significant number of poorer countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got to the bottom of this specific error message, but I did manage to get another J2ME Polish demo project up and running in the end - from which point I could adapt the project as per my requirements.

Basically, I had no joy with Netbeans 8.0, so I used Netbeans 7.2.1. And the demo project that worked for me (which you select in the last step of the J2ME Polish New Project wizard) was the **datefield** project.

I also found it's important to select a specific device to get the project to compile - I just selected the `Generic/midp2` device (found under the `Virtual` section in the wizard) and make sure it is selected as the current configuration when you build the project.

I expect there will be many other variations that also work, but after a lot of farting around, this is the combination that eventually worked for me - so hopefully this will be a good starting point for someone else.